# php select - compare last two rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$q = "SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4 "
       ."FROM ".TBL_MYTBL." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = $database->query($q);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)) {
    echo "Error displaying info";
    return;
}
if($num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Database table empty";
    return;
}
```

If `column1` from the last row is bigger than the same column from the second-to-last row, then I want to do `action1`, otherwise `action2`.
How can I do that comparison?

Comment: btw: `$num_rows < 0` will never be true.... (Returns number of rows in the result set.)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a303c/1 check this link it may help u

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccf338b/4 check this for another scenario

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is fetch both rows from the database and then you can compare the result in PHP using if statements.

```
$q = "SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4 
    FROM ".TBL_MYTBL." 
    ORDER BY date DESC 
    LIMIT 2";
$result = $database->query($q)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (2 == count($result)) {
    if ($result[1]['column1'] > $result[0]['column1']) {
        // action 1
    } else {
        // action 2
    }
}
```

If there is a chance that your query might not return two rows then you need to handle that appropriately.